# Error 500 Failed to upload file using Delphi Indy

Tags: delphi, file-upload, indy

I'm trying to upload a file to oboom.com i logged in successfully but when try to post the file i get that error

> HTTP/1.1500 Internal Server Error.

with this respose text

`[500,"illegal post header","Content-Transfer-Encoding"]`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: tstringlist;
  html: string;
  clHttpRequest1: tclHttpRequest;
  SSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  params: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  HTTP, HTTP2: tidhttp;
begin
  params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  S := tstringlist.Create;
  HTTP2 := tidhttp.Create(nil);
  try
    cookie := tidcookiemanager.Create(nil);
    SSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    HTTP2.IOHandler := SSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    HTTP2.HandleRedirects := False;
    HTTP2.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
    HTTP2.ReadTimeout := 10000;
    HTTP2.CookieManager := cookie;
    HTTP2.AllowCookies := True;
    HTTP2.Request.UserAgent :=
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36';
    HTTP2.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    HTTP2.Request.ContentEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
    HTTP2.Request.Accept := '*/*';
    HTTP2.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
    S.Values['auth'] := 'email@gmail.com';
    S.Values['pass'] := 'password';
    S.Values['app_id'] := '5hwaJUcDicXprlV3gjaB';
    S.Values['app_session'] := '288196272';
    html := HTTP2.Post('https://www.oboom.com/1.0/login', S);
  finally
    HTTP2.Free;
    S.Free;
  end;
  token := ExtractBetween(html, 'session":"', '"');
  try
    HTTP := tidhttp.Create;
    HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    HTTP.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
    HTTP.AllowCookies := True;
    HTTP.CookieManager := cookie;
    HTTP.Request.Referer := 'http://upload.oboom.com';
    HTTP.Request.ContentType :=
      'multipart/form-data; boundary=----------GI3Ef1cH2GI3gL6ae0Ef1KM7Ef1gL6';
    HTTP.Request.Accept := '*/*';
    HTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip,deflate';
    HTTP.ConnectTimeout := 20000;
    HTTP.ReadTimeout := 20000;
    HTTP.Request.UserAgent :=
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36';
    params.AddFile('file', 'C:\Users\M\Pictures\Martin.jpg', );
    HTTP.Post('http://upload.oboom.com/1.0/ul?token=' + token +
      '&parent=1&name_policy=rename', params);
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
    params.Free;
    cookie.Free;
  end;
  memo1.Text := html;
end;
```

i have googled hours for a solution but no luck :/

tried  this way :

```
 Params.AddFile('file', 'C:\Users\M\Pictures\Martin.jpg','application/octet-stream');
 Params.AddFile('file', 'C:\Users\M\Pictures\Martin.jpg','multipart/form-data');
```

but same error

i have tried clever internet compenent and succeeded  uploading the file but i would like to use indy ..

i use delphi X3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of these lines:

```
HTTP2.Request.ContentEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
```

```
HTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip,deflate';
```

`TIdHTTP` manages those values for you based on whether its `Compressor` property is assigned and enabled.  And, you are not sending a compressed request, so those values should not be used anyway.

Also, you need to get rid of this line:

```
HTTP.Request.ContentType :=
  'multipart/form-data; boundary=----------GI3Ef1cH2GI3gL6ae0Ef1KM7Ef1gL6';
```

`Post()` manages that value for you, especially the `boundary`, which `TIdMultipartFormDtaStream` generates dynamically.

**Update** the only other place that `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is used is on the individual fields of the `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`.  Each `TIdFormDataField` has a `ContentTransfer` property.  `AddFile()` initializes it to `'binary'`, but you can also set it to a blank string to disable the header:

```
params.AddFile(...).ContentTransfer := '';
```

Comment: WORKED like it should , Thank you